# SQL- Convert Sum int to Decimal

Tags: sql-server, casting, int, decimal

I've been trying to change this sum to a decimal.  The calculation sets a target for the number of specific tasks to be completed within the employees working hours. The result is the problem as it continues to give the result as int.

`((sum(IsNull([Employee Hours],0))/NullIf([ProcessTime],0))as decimal(6,2)) as [Planned Tasks],`

I've tried both CAST and CONVERT but nothing seems to have worked and the result is still showing as int.

This is the last script I tried:

`Cast((sum(IsNull([Employee Hours],0))/NullIf([ProcessTime],0))as decimal(6,2)) as [Planned Tasks],`

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) Explain why your code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the problem is not the data type but the *result*.  Your code looks like SQL Server, and SQL Server does *integer* division, so `1/2` is `0`, not `0.5`.  To get a decimal, convert to a non-integer number -- I tend to do this by multiplying by `1.0`:

```
Cast(sum(coalesce([Employee Hours], 0) * 1.0 /
     NullIf([ProcessTime], 0) as decimal(6, 2)
    ) as [Planned Tasks],
```